# EJB CMT TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW doesn't work

Tags: jakarta-ee, transactions, ejb-3.0

```
    @Stateless    @LocalBean
    public class MySLSB {

            @Resource
            SessionContext ctx;
            @PersistenceContext(unitName = "myPU")
            EntityManager em;

            public void T1() {
                em.persist(new MyEntity(1L)); //T1 created!
/* wrong call to plain java object               
 T2();
 */     
//corrected by lookup its business object first 
ctx.getBusinessObject(MySLSB.class).T2();   
     ctx.setRollbackOnly();
            }

            @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
            public void T2() {
                em.persist(new MyEntity(2L)); //T2 created!
            }
        }
```

The client calls T1(), at first T2 as a new Transaction should be committed, 
but T1 will be rolled back.

> Expected result:
>
> T1: insert into myentity set id=1;
>
> T2: insert into myentity set id=2;
>
> T2: commit;
>
> T1: rollback;
>
> -> The row with id=2 is created in DB.
>
> Actual result:
>
> insert into myentity set id=1;
>
> insert into myentity set id=2;
>
> rollback;
>
> -> Nothing is created in DB.

What's the problem? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@Solution**

The problem is solved. i made a naive mistake.

The call to T2() should lookup its business object, direct call to T2() IS merely to its plain java object.

i updated the code on the question above, making everything worked just as expected.

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier to declare self reference `@EJB MySLSB me;` and to call `me.T2();` instead of using `ctx.getBusinessObject(MySLSB.class)`. But the sense is the same.